# C# WebClient.DownloadFile grabbing CSV from URL Format is not supported error.

Tags: c#, webclient, visual-studio-2015

quick question for you. I am trying to do a simple console application to grab a file from a URL. I wish I could say I know more about the site I'm grabbing it from, but all I know is that you put the parameters into the URL for which file you want, and when you go to the URL, you automatically start a download for it (this is what happens in a browser anyways).

So I used the code below and it does create a file but the only text in the file is the message below. I tried making the filename variable to the same as what the file name would be if you just downloaded it via the browser but that didn't work either, same error. Any ideas?

Error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><MtxExportingResult Result="Failure" Date="7/28/2015" Time="6:25:51 AM"><Error Type="FormatNotSupported">The format 'CSVExtract.csv' is not supported.</Error></MtxExportingResult>
```

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Net;

namespace ReceiveAndFormatCPCSV
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string remoteUri = "https://www.downloadurl.com/ServerEPS/Export/AllFileRecords.xpt?IdentifierNumber=666&username=Username&password=Password&format=CSV";
        string fileName = "CPExtract.csv", myStringWebResource = null;

        WebClient cpClient = new WebClient();

        myStringWebResource = remoteUri + fileName;
        Console.WriteLine("Downloading File \"{0}\" from \"{1}\" .......\n\n", fileName, myStringWebResource);

        cpClient.DownloadFile(myStringWebResource, fileName);
        Console.WriteLine("Successfully Downloaded File \"{0}\" from \"{1}\"", fileName, myStringWebResource);
        Console.WriteLine("\nDownloaded file saved in the following file system folder:\n\t");


    }
}
}
```

any advice would be appreciated. Thank you,

Comment: You're appending the filename to the url, but the url ends with a query parameter "format", which means that the parameter "format" no longer equals "CSV", it's "CSVCPExtract.csv".  It seems likely that you're supposed to do something else with the filename (e.g. replace the part of the url that already looks like a filename: AllFileRecords.xpt ).

Answer (score 1):

The result of

> myStringWebResource = remoteUri + filename;

is a badly formed URI which ends with "&format=CSVCPExtract.csv".

Delete that line and you should get different results.  (Although you'll never catch me putting that URI into a browser or web client...it looks suspicious.)

The first argument to Download file is the URI to download the file from.  The second is the local filename to download it to.  Since your remoteUri includes parameters, and one of those parameters is IdentifierNumber, it appears that it points to a specific file.  The code you copied and pasted off the web performs this concatenation because it plans to use the same local file name as the filename on the remote server.